# What are the cons of the riblet architecture in uber?

Tags: uber-api, web-architecture, iosdeployment

I am studying the current architecture of uber rider app and I got to know the current rider app was evolved from MVC to a specific architecture called riblet, which is designed on top of viper by Uber themselves. As I understood riblets is independently testable pieces that each have a single purpose. I'm aware that the new architecture is capable of handling performance and scalability. I am interested in knowing the cons of riblet architecture.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okey. I found some **cons of the riblet architecture**. I will post them here to discuss with anyone who is interested. The main cons are as follows,

- Since there is a higher number of independent riblets communicating  through their interfaces, there is a probability of failure of a particular interface compared to a system with fewer components.
- Yes testing a single riblet is easy yet it makes integrations and handling the requests among riblets more complicated.
- Changing the technology stack in the long run is difficult

Comment: This article will help you build your knowledge on riblet and mvc:
https://eng.uber.com/new-rider-app/

Comment: @AbidAli Thanks a lot. Actually I referred actually. Just wanted to have a discussion here. Thanks Again